# automatically generating protobuf annotated classes

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers, angular-dart

Is there a way to automatically generate json_serialable  annotations to protobuf generated classes?
How it stands now i am not able to serialize json to dart protobuf generated classes and i want serialize to a json output from a golang based rest service.

Comment: Protobuf is explicitly a serialization concept - I don't understand why you need to involve a `json_serializable`, you can use `writeToJson()` on the protobuf object. https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/serialization#protobuf-example

Comment: they currently do not support named fields
i have a http response model in golang that i generated the dart equivalent to and now i want to call on the golang http JSON endpoint and serialize the response with dart

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to accomplish this today. The build system, `build_runner` does not allow overwriting files so it isn't possible to programmatically insert these annotations into the protobuf generated code.

This would require either an option in the protobuf generator to change the serialization format, or another serialization framework built on top of protobuf that would understand their source and can generate the custom serialization required.